# WPF custom datagrid UI virtualization not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a custom datagrid which is styled as below

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="1" />
        <!-- This is needed to force DG to have a non-default value.  Otherwise the DGR.DetailsVisibility cannot have a value of VisibleWhenSelected by default. -->
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode"
                Value="VisibleWhenSelected" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode"
                Value="Recycling" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="EnableColumnVirtualization"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="EnableRowVirtualization"
                Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false"
                                      Name="DG_ScrollViewer">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <!--Left Column Header Corner -->
                                        <Border BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=HeaderBorderBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                                                Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=HeaderBackground}"
                                                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=CellsPanelHorizontalOffset}"
                                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                        <!--Column Headers-->
                                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                                        Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                                        Visibility="Visible">
                                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                                                                <Border Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=NameHeaderBackground}">
                                                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                                                </Border>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Style>
                                            </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Style>
                                        </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>

                                        <!--Column Header Splitter-->
                                        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                                                      Grid.Column="0"
                                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                      Height="4"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                      Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=NameHeaderBackground}"
                                                      Foreground="Transparent"
                                                      Cursor="SizeWE" />

                                        <!-- Line separates the column header with the content-->
                                        <Canvas Grid.Row="1"
                                                Grid.Column="0"
                                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                Height="1.5"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=HorizontalGridLinesBrush}" />


                                        <!--DataGrid content-->
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                                Grid.Row="2"
                                                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                                CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

                                        <ScrollBar Grid.Row="0"
                                                   Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                                   Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                                   Orientation="Vertical"
                                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                                   Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                                   Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}" />

                                        <Grid Grid.Row="3"
                                              Grid.Column="1">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset}" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1"
                                                       Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                                       Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                                       Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!-- The DataGrid is always rotated either +90 or -90 degrees, depending on whether the Trend Control scrolls to the left or to the right.
                         So, the vertical scrollbar is rendered as a horizontal scrollbar -->
                        <Trigger SourceName="DG_ScrollViewer"
                                 Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                                 Value="Visible">
                            <Setter Property="IsShowingHorizontalScrollBar"
                                    Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In this datagrid, itemssource is being dynamically updated using a background thread. The number of rows are usually limited and it will not be more than 10 but the number of columns will be in thousands. Though virtualization has been enabled, it doesn't seem to be working. The column virtualization is expected to work but it is not working. The UI is not at all responsive while the datagrid is loaded.

Looking forward to any kind of input/suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Show the xaml where you are using this custom datagrid, how it is put in the layout, it might take more vertical space than you realize.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not placed in xaml. Its dynamically created in c# and no specific properties are set at that point.